# How to relevel a factor in R with 100 levels in R?

Tags: r

I have a factor variable that has 100 levels with 0s and 1s. For example: 00000001, 01000000, 11000000, 00010001. Each level has 8 digits with 0 and 1s. What I want to do is to reorder the levels in a way that the sum of 1s is from smallest to largest. For example, I want 10000000, 01000000, 00100000, and other levels that only contains one 1. Followed by levels contain two 1s, and up to levels contain eight 1s. Is that any way that I can do that automatically instead of doing this manually?

```
df[,1] <- factor(df[,1], levels=c("000", "001","100", "010","101","110","011","111"......))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dummy data

```
d <- c("00010001", "00000001", "01000000", "11000000")
```

You can use `gregexpr` to count how many 1s are in each entry of your character vecotr.

```
num_ones <- lengths(gregexpr("1", d))
> num_ones
[1] 2 1 1 2
```

You can then split your vector, grouping it by the number of ones. Within each group you can optionally sort decreasing or increasing. Finally, unlist everything which returns a sorted vector.

```
unlist(lapply(split(d, num_ones), sort))
> unlist(lapply(split(d, num_ones), sort))
        11         12         21         22 
"00000001" "01000000" "00010001" "11000000"
```

You apply this method to the levels of your factor re-order them like so:

```
d <- factor(c("00010001", "00000001", "01000000", "11000000"))
lvls <- levels(d)
num_ones <- lengths(gregexpr("1", lvls))
sorted <- unlist(lapply(split(lvls, num_ones), sort))

d <- factor(d, levels = sorted)
> d
[1] 00010001 00000001 01000000 11000000
Levels: 00000001 01000000 00010001 11000000
```

Comment: Hi Zalazny7, thanks for your reply. It worked and sorted the values. The only thing is that I do not want to sort the values, I only want to sort the levels. Is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: I did the d <- factor(d, levels = sorted), but I have 1000 data points for the 100 levels. So some data points have the same levels (values). When I run this, it gives me: Warning message:
In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated

Comment: Make sure you are doing that regex and split on the levels of your factor. Not the values